# Loss keeps getting more wiggly. What wrong?

Tags: neural-network, loss-function

My network's loss function seems fine until 1500th iteration, then it becomes extremaly wiggly and keeps jumping up and down. I have no idea what the reason might be. The learning rate is low only 0.0075. Can someone explain what's wrong ?

[image]